# CSS doesn't work, only on mobile 3G/4G

Tags: css, mobile, compilation, less

So yesterday I've quickly rebuild my personal website, everything was working great. It's a pretty simple website, nothing fancy. I used the Twitter Bootstrap, LESS CSS and some HTML5 video.

But then, when I checked the website on my mobile (Nexus 5), I've seen that the CSS/LESS was only understood partially by my mobile browser (Chrome). I've tried several things in order to make it work, but I can't figure out why it works only partially.

EDIT : if I use my WIFI to browse the website on mobile, it works perfect.
EDIT 2 : if I set Chrome on mobile to "view desktop website", the responsive works great, CSS works great too. But I still don't know what's wrong.

Here is what I see on mobile

[image]

Here is what it's supposed to be http://bastienald.net/

I really don't know what went wrong

Comment: wow...connection based css...never heard of this...+1 !! :)

Comment: Neither did I ! First time I ever seen this problem. How lucky am I to witness this when doing my own website ? :)

Comment: m pretty sure its some coding error...can you reproduce this in a fiddle??

Comment: I'll try, I am thinking that i has to do something with the order of the CSS files. I'll try some new things, if it doesn't work, I'll try to make it happen on Fiddle. But being a mobile only problem, I don't thing I'll be able to reproduce it.

Comment: simple advice...place `mobile-only` css in the last...because the order in which css files are called is also important!! :)

Comment: oO well, I just switched from "view mobile" to "view desktop" and then back to "view mobile" on my smartphone browser, and now it seems to be working fine. But I really don't get it.
Could you try on some mobile device and tell me what you see ? I would be really thankful. <3

Comment: i don't have a mobile...i use pager...but follow my advice from above comment and u would be fine!! :)

Comment: Thanks, I currently have the mobile CSS set before the "medium" and "large" devices CSS. I'll put it in last, following your advice ! Thank you ! I'll check if nothing has broken while I was writting here ^^

Comment: sure thing...if its successful, i'll post it as answer then!! :)

Comment: Well, even before that. It now seems to work perfectly, wether I put the mobile CSS at last or at first. Meh, that's the first time I don't get what's going on here. FYI I use the queries from the bootstrap too : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries which has always worked perfectly before. So...

Comment: To sum up : the problem is now resolved, the CSS is the same as before. I've just once switched from "mobile view" to "desktop view" and then back to "mobile view" in my mobile browser. Then tried switching from WIFI to 4G multiple times, to be sure. Now no problem at all. Everything works.

Comment: then it browser cache issue for sure!! :)

Comment: That's what I thought too finally, I've also cleared the cache on my mobile at last. To be 100% sure it's the good CSS which is loaded. Rah ! "Cache problems... make you look stupid since the beginning of the internet" ^^
Will you post it as an answer or should I ? :)

Comment: you post it and mark as accepted...i'll upvote it :)

Comment: Ah... I can't answer my own question because I'm a new member. Must wait at least 8 hours.

Comment: Ok, will do that later then :) Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Are you compiling the LESS CSS?

If not, it could be that the desktop rendered of Chrome is able to read the LESS CSS fine whereas mobile isn't.

Comment: At last, it seemed to be a cache related problem. I've switched to "view desktop website" on mobile, everything worked fine then. And thus I switched back to "view mobile" and everything was ok then. 

I also cleared the cached after that.

I am currently posting the answer I've found. :)